# Java framework for tabbed windows (like Firefox)

Tags: java, firefox, frameworks, tabs

I'm looking for a Java framework which provides tabbed windows, as in Firefox, i.e. tabs can be dragged out to create a new window and dragged back in.

Do you know anything which can do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The NetBeans platform can do that.

Comment: I'm looking for a library to do this in my own code. Are you saying I can do this with the netbeans gui editor or that they have a developed and made available a library to do this?

Comment: If you base your application on the NetBeans platform, you'll get the window managing for "free". I don't think you can rip out the window subsystem from the platform and integrate it into a non RCP application